# Error con order by en entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Estoy agrupando los años de un listado en una base de datos, en sql server lo hago así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ejercicio FROM DASH_CLIENTES order by ejercicio asc
```

Obteniendo la respuesta :

```
ejercicio
________
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
```

Para Entity Framework hice esto:

```
var result = bd.DashClientes.OrderBy(l => l.Ejercicio).AsNoTracking().Select(l => l.Ejercicio).Distinct().ToList();
```

cosa que recibo la información en el siguiente orden:

```
[
    "2020",
    "2019",
    "2018",
    "2021",
    "2022",
    "2017",
    "2023"
]
```

Y aunque coloque `OrderByDescending` sigue obteniendo el mismo orden anterior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoca el `OrderBy` luego del `Distinct`

```
  var result = bd.DashClientes
                 .AsNoTracking()
                 .Select(l => l.Ejercicio)
                 .Distinct()
                 .OrderBy(e => e)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono pero me surgió una duda ¿Porque el integrar `OrderBy` antes que `Distinct`

Comment: Es por cómo está implementado `Distinct` según la documentación dice que "retorna una secuencia no ordenada de elementos" . Por eso se ordena hasta el final. Ref  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Distinct__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__:~:text=TSource%3E%2C%20IEqualityComparer%3CTSource%3E)-,method%20returns%20an%20unordered%20sequence,-that%20contains%20no

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la información